# How to backup Signal app on sd card instead of internal storage?

Tags: backup, sd-card, instant-messenger

I want to backup the signal app on my Android phone at the sd card for my new phone. In the app there is no option to choose the pathway, it is automatically saved in the internal storage. However, the app now has 4,7 GB and my storage is only 16 GB big and nearly full. With the storage needed for the system I'd basically had to remove everything else to make it work. So the backup always starts but stops at some point and no backup is created.

I tried

- deleting other apps and media even though I calculated it would still not be enough space and it wasn't.
- removing the /signal/backups folder manually several times before or while the backup was creating but the folder at the sd card still remained empty and was recreated in the internal storage
- finding an option to move the entire app to the sd card as possible with other apps but this has to be in a forced way if possible
- making the used space by signal smaller by deleting saved pictures by signal in the internal storage and by deleting chats but the space remained the same size ...
- google. But what I found in the internet was not much and I did not understand what to do. Like using tasker or osmand somehow?

Do you know a creative or clever way of forcing Android and Signal to backup on the sd card?

Comment: Does your phone allow you to save other apps to the sd card?

Comment: yes, I moved other apps to the sd card, but not all apps are possible on my phone